# Remover página da pilha em Ionic

Tags: ionic, angular

Tenho a seguinte estrutura

```
Home > Page 1
```

A minha Page 1 a cada 10 segundos realiza uma requisição http. Percebi que quando eu movimento da Page 1 para a Home, continua realizando as requisições.

Gostaria de saber como eu posso remover da pilha assim que eu sair da página.

Eu tentei:

```
  ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.navController
    .push(HomePage)
    .then(() => {
      // first we find the index of the current view controller:
      const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
      // then we remove it from the navigation stack
      this.nav.remove(index - 1);
    });
  }
```

Pra trocar de página eu utilizo a seguinte função:

```
  rotaHome() {
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
```

Comment: Tenta fazer um unsubscribe do observable que esta fazendo as requisições indesejadas onDestroy

Comment: Eu tentei no onDestroy, quando troca de página, em vários lugares diferentes, mas as requisições continuam, consegui só através da maneira que publiquei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

A quem se interessar, eu consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
this.IntervalId = setInterval(()=> {
  this.listaPerguntas(); },12000); //A cada 5 minutos verifica se existe uma nova pergunta
}

  rotaHome() {
    clearInterval(this.IntervalId);
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage).then(() =>
      this.navController.popToRoot()
    );
  }
```

Acredito que não é a maneira mais recomendada, não consegui entender porque depois do pop a página continua realizando requisições, porém o clearInterval funcionou bem no momento.